# How to automatically assign a route to client in Windows Server PPTP VPN?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, tcpip, static-routes

Is there a way to configure PPTP VPN on Windows Server which automatically tells the client to add a route for the private network?

I have to do it manually on every PC (once) using following command for example:

```
 route add 192.168.111.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.112.101 -p
```

and assigning a fixed IP address for every account.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't actually tried it, but I believe [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728159.aspx) should do what you want if you're using a windows (?2003+) domain.

At the bottom of the 'Dial-in' tab of the active directory user properties for the user you want to enable it for there's an 'Apply static routes' checkbox, and a button for entering those routes.

Comment: Never worked for me. Don't know why...

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you configure your DHCP server to provide the proper routes to the client via [option 121, *"Classless Static Routes"*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3442). The VPN client's DHCP client will send a `DHCPINFORM` after connecting to the VPN and should receive the routes from the DHCP server. This works in Windows 7 and, if memory serves, in both Vista and XP as well.

Comment: Necessary comment is that class-based routes addition should be disabled in connection configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the routes via a [DHCP option, I think it's 249](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc227282.aspx).  Add it to the scope that is providing addresses to the RRAS server.